# What is wrong with my understanding of "__shared__" variables in cuda?

Tags: cuda

After reading the manual of NVIDIA, I wrotea parrell reduction code as follows:

```
__global__ void kernel(int *devData)
{
    __shared__ int sum;
    int i = blockDim.x  * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
        sum = 0;
    __syncthreads();
    sum += devData[i];
    __syncthreads();
    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
        printf("sum of block %d is %d\n", blockIdx.x, sum);
}

int main(void)
{
    // init device
    int devIdx = 0;
    cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;
    gpuDeviceInit(devIdx);
    int i;
    int data[100];
    int *devData;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        data[i] = 1;
    err = cudaMalloc(&devData, 100 * sizeof(int));
    checkCudaErrors(err);

    // copy data to device
    err = cudaMemcpy(devData, data, 100 * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    checkCudaErrors(err);

    int blocksPerGrid = 10;
    int threadsPerBlock = 10;
    
    // call kernel function
    kernel <<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>> (devData);
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to sum integers for each block and then print this sum.
But I found the result was as follows:

```
sum of block 0 is 1
sum of block 6 is 1
sum of block 2 is 1
sum of block 8 is 1
sum of block 1 is 1
sum of block 7 is 1
sum of block 4 is 1
sum of block 3 is 1
sum of block 9 is 1
sum of block 5 is 1
```

The result I expected was 10.Is the __shared__ variable "sum" shared by every thread in a block? What's wrong with my understanding of "__shared__"  variables in cuda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have multiple threads trying to access (read-modify-write) `sum` at the same time, here:

```
sum += devData[i];
```

This doesn't work for either global or shared data in CUDA (i.e. CUDA won't sort that out for you, automatically).  To sort this out, the usual approaches are either to use atomics or else to use a [canonical parallel reduction](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf)

There are numerous questions on both of these topics here on the `cuda` SO tag, and you can get some focused training on parallel reduction methods in unit 5 of [this online training series](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/cuda-training-series/).

For example, in your code, a trivial change to "fix" would be to replace the above line of code with an atomic add:

```
atomicAdd(&sum,devData[i]);
```

atomics force serialization, so a preferred approach is a canonical parallel reduction.